# adding styles to ParagraphHeadings in Google DocumentApp puts everything in the document outline?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm generating Google Docs from a big spreadsheet and I want to format them, but also have the Document Outline work properly.

Right now I can get that working if I don't do any styling, but if I add styling to the ParagraphHeading types suddenly my "NORMAL" paragraphs end up in the outline along with the "H1" types, which isn't what I want.

Here's sample code that illustrates the problem:

```
function makeASampleDoc() {
    var doc = DocumentApp.create("aaa_docOutlineTest" + " " + Date.now() );
    var body = doc.getBody();
      
    // two styles: one for questions, one for answers
    var qStyle={};
    qStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE]=10;
    qStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]=true;
    qStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#000000';
    qStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR]='#DDDDDD';
     
    var aStyle={};
    aStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE]=12;
    aStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]=false;
    aStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#222222';
    aStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR]='#FFFFFF';
    
    // some q&a's for the doc
    var questions = ["Question number one?", "Questions number two?", "Question number three?"];
    var answers = ["Thoughtful answer to question number one...", "I really have no position on question number two.", "Question number three is a real head-scratcher..."];
    
    // make the doc
    for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      let question = body.appendParagraph(questions[i]);
      question.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
    
      let answer = body.appendParagraph(answers[i]);
      answer.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL);
    
      //uncomment these lines to add the styles - now everything appears in the document outline
      //question.setAttributes(qStyle);
      //answer.setAttributes(aStyle);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue I saw was both `HEADING1` and `NORMAL` after `setAttributes` is shown in the outline which wass unexpected.

Workaround is that, you can use `SUBTITLE` instead of `NORMAL`.

**Code:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  let question = body.appendParagraph(questions[i]);
  let answer = body.appendParagraph(answers[i]);

  question.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  answer.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.SUBTITLE);

  question.setAttributes(qStyle);
  answer.setAttributes(aStyle);
}
```

**Output:**

[image: outline sample]

Comment: Huh! It works! It feels a little hacky and like it *shouldn't* be that way (c'mon, Google!), but it works - thank you!